# Rails 5 Upgrade, can't resolve dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Upgrading from Rails 4.2.8 to Rails 5.0.2 results in the error message below. I am not sure how to resolve the dependencies. The ruby version is 2.5.1. I've been able to run this app and the test suite with Rails 4.2.8, though I have seen some excessive printing by a lower version of carrierwave, so I'd like to be able to upgrade that, but it requires Rails 5.

## Error Message

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    actionpack-action_caching was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      actionpack (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.2)

    simple_form was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.2)

    simple_form was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0)

    validate_url was resolved to 1.0.8, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    friendly_id (~> 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    active_hash (~> 1.4.1) was resolved to 1.4.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 2.2.2)

    carrierwave was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "http":
  In Gemfile:
    http

    twitter (~> 5.15.0) was resolved to 5.15.0, which depends on
      http (< 0.10, >= 0.4)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.2)

    interactor-rails (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
      rails (< 5.3, >= 4.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.2)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.8, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.2.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sprockets

    sass-rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.8, which depends on
      sprockets (< 4.0, >= 2.8)
```

## Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'active_hash', '~> 1.4.1'
gem 'avatars.io'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'devise'
gem 'diffy'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'fog'
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.5.3.2'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'haml'
gem 'html5shiv-js-rails'
gem 'http'
gem 'interactor-rails', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11.4'
gem 'rails', '5.0.2'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'ruby-mp3info', '>= 0.8.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'stamp'
gem 'twitter', '~> 5.15.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'validate_url'
gem 'xml-simple', '~> 1.1.5'
gem 'will_paginate'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'scout_apm'
  gem 'sentry-raven'
  # gem 'unicorn-worker-killer'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'm'
  gem 'minitest-rails', '~> 2.2.0'
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.9', require: false
  gem 'timecop'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end
```

Comment: I think it is because you're fixing version of a lot of gems, which cannot be automatically resolved by running bundle. Try to remove fixed version of error gem, and try again

Comment: How did you try to update to Rails 5.0.2? What steps did you take, want command did you run?

Answer (score 1):

```
    sass-rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.8, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
```

railties 5.2 will conflict with the rest of Rails at 5.0 - you need to restrict `sass-rails` to `< 5.0.8`

Answer (score 0):

back up your gemfile first and then try with this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'active_hash'
gem 'avatars.io'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'devise'
gem 'diffy'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'fog'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'haml'
gem 'html5shiv-js-rails'
gem 'http'
gem 'interactor-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'ruby-mp3info'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'stamp'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'validate_url'
gem 'xml-simple'
gem 'will_paginate'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'scout_apm'
  gem 'sentry-raven'
  # gem 'unicorn-worker-killer'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'm'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'timecop'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end
```

run

```
bundle update
```

Comment: But they want Rails 5.0.2

Comment: add rails gem in your gem file "gem 'rails', '5.0.2' ", then try
command:- gem install rails -v '5.0.2', then try command:- bundle install. are you using gemset ?